# Redirecionamento após Action php

Tags: php, mysql

O formulário do cliente, apenas enviava emails, agora preciso que além dele enviar os emails, os dados fiquem armazenados no banco de dados, isto eu consegui realizar, ficou assim meu html :

```
  <form action="insert.php" method="post">
                            <h4>Seus dados:</h4>
                            <input type="text" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome..." class="quote-form-element" />
                            <input type="text" name="Cidade" placeholder="Cidade/UF..." class="quote-form-element quote-form-client-email last" />
                            <input type="text" name="Telefone" placeholder="Telefone..." class="quote-form-element telefone" />
                            <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail..." class="quote-form-element quote-form-client-email last contact_email"
                            />                                

                            <button class="button button-navy-blue send-quote" type="submit">Simular meu consórcio <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>



                            <div class="quote-form-thanks">

                                <div class="quote-form-thanks-content">

                                    Obrigado pelo seu interesse, retornaremos em breve ;).
                                    <span class="quote-form-thanks-close">Fechar</span>

                                </div>
                        </form>
```

PHP para salvar os dados no mysql

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("novo", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO tablename (nome, cidade, telefone, email )
VALUES
('$_POST[Nome]','$_POST[Cidade]','$_POST[Telefone]','$_POST[Email]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))


mysql_close($con)
?>
```

PHP email

```
$title = 'Nova simulação via website';


        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n".
                   "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n".
                   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n".
                    "From: ". $_POST['clientName'] ." <". $_POST['clientEmail'] .">\n".
                   "Reply-to: ". $_POST['clientName'] ." <". $_POST['clientEmail'] .">\n".
                   "Date: ". date( "r" ). "\n";


        $values = $_POST['values'];


        $rows = '';
        if (count($values) > 0) {
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $values ); $i++ ) {

            $rows .= '<tr>

                          <td style="width: 200px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 10px;">'. $values[$i]['name'] .'</td>
                          <td style="border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 10px;">'. $values[$i]['value'] .'</td>

                      </tr>';
        }


        $content = '<table style="width: 600px; font-size: 11px; border-collapse: collapse;">'. $rows .'</table>';


        $result = mail(
            OWNER_EMAIL,
            "=?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode( $title ) ."?=",
            $content,
            $headers
        );}
```

JS email

```
 $(".send-quote").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).parent(),
        b = a.parent().parent(),
        d = (b.data("quote-form-for"), {}),
        f = "",
        g = "",
        h = "",
        i = "",
        j = !1;
    a.find(".quote-form-element").each(function(a) {
        f = $(this).attr("name"), "undefined" != typeof f && f !== !1 || (f = $(this).data("name")), $(this).hasClass("checkbox") ? g = "yes" == $(this).data("checked") ? $(this).children(".checkbox-values").children(".checkbox-value-checked").text() : $(this).children(".checkbox-values").children(".checkbox-value-unchecked").text() : (g = $(this).is("input") || $(this).is("select") ? $(this).val() : $(this).text(), $(this).is("input") && "" == g || $(this).is("select") && "-" == g ? (j = !0, $(this).addClass("error")) : $(this).removeClass("error")), $(this).hasClass("quote-form-client-name") && (h = $(this).val()), $(this).hasClass("quote-form-client-email") && (i = $(this).val()), d[a] = {
            name: f,
            value: g
        }, a++
    }), 0 == j && $.ajax({
        url: "_assets/submit.php",
        data: {
            send: "quote-form",
            values: d,
            clientName: h,
            clientEmail: i
        },
        type: "post",
        success: function(b) {
            a.children(".quote-form-thanks").fadeIn(300)
        }
    })
}), $(".quote-form-thanks-close").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).parent().parent();
    a.fadeOut(300)
}),
```

Após enviar o formulário, ele redireciona para o `insert.php.

Quando apenas enviava o email, ele apresentava uma mensagem de que havia sido enviado, na mesma página, e depois o usuário fechava o formulário.

Teria como ele não redirecionar?

Caso queiram ver como é a página, é essa [aqui](http://consorciomenegalli.com.br)

Comment: Na verdade eu respondi,e  agora lendo de novo eu não entendi bem o que desejas... Você quer que ele não redirecione ? O que exatamente desejas ? Você quer que o `action` aponte para a  mesma página ? Ou como ?

Comment: Onde está o código referente ao envio do email ? Acho que estou começando a entender,,,

Comment: @MagicHat editei a pergunta, coloquei os códigos. Eu nao sei nem se é possível enviar para o email e armazenar no BD. O que realmente gostaria que funcionasse, é que a mensagem de que  foi enviado, permanece, como ocorre na página

Answer (score 1):

Podes adicionar no seu arquivo `insere.php` um redirecionamento :

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
header("location:pagina_destino.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando oque nosso amigo @MagicHat disse..

Podes também personalizar com um `alert`:

```js
alert('SUA MENSAGEM AQUI'); 
window.location='index.php';
```

Ficando assim em **PHP**

**`if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('SUA MENSAGEM AQUI'); window.location='index.php'; </script>";`**